# Python indentation error while loop

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error, indentation

```
while x <= 9:
    result = usertype()
    if result == 'Correct':
```

I am receiving an indentation error on the "t" of result in "result = usertype(). Can anybody explain this?

*EDIT
I have tried rewriting it, and I checked to make sure that all of the indents are indeed indents and not spaces. Getting really frustrated and very confused now. I am thinking it might possibly be something in a previous line causing the problem.

*EDIT 2
Error copied from Command Prompt because IDLE doesn't work for me:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    result = usertype()
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>         if result == 'Correct':
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if result == 'Correct':
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             x = x + 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = x + 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             y = y + 5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    y = y + 5
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         else:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             x = x + 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = x + 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             y = y - a2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    y = y - a2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     return y
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return y
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

**Solved!**
I'm not sure how, but I copy pasted my code into IDLE, untabified all regions then tabified again. I read somewhere else on SO to do that, so problem solved!

Here is the entire program:

```
import random

def usertype(raw_input):
    randletter = random.choice('qwer')
    print randletter
    userinput = raw_input('')
    if userinput == randletter:
        return 'Correct'
    else:
        return 'Incorrect'

def usertypetest(raw_input):
    x=0
    y=0
    while x <= 9:
        result = usertype()
        if result == 'Correct':
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 5
        else:
            x = x + 1
            y = y - a2
    return y

print usertypetest(raw_input)
```

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?  That is usually the cause of these types of errors.

Comment: Yes... from ":" of while press enter and type the code new

Comment: I rewrote the code, still receiving this error. I will post the entire program now.

Comment: Could you also post the full error, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't something wrong with the code as posted. But you may have mixed tabs and spaces in your file which causes Python to get confused about indentation. Check your text editor settings to see if you can highlight these characters.

Comment: I checked, they were all tabbed. I rewrote the incorrect areas, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++, there's a option to show white Spaces and Tab.

Go to `View>> Show Sybmol>> show white Spaces and Tab`
(*white dots*)

[image]

You need to find something similar in other IDEs.